# Running jQuery call in Firebug Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, firebug

Sorry, new to Firebug.  I really find being able to run javascript in the Firebug console window helpful.  However, I don't seem to be able to run jQuery calls in the console.  For example, in my executing javascript in my page, I may make the call to get a value:

```
   jQuery('#an_element_value').text()
```

However, I cannot execute this in the console.  In order to retrieve this value from the page in the console I have to execute:

```
   document.getElementById('an_element_value').innerHTML
```

Is there a way to execute jQuery calls and reference page elements through jQuery in the Firebug console?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Because running jQuery(...) and $(...) seems to work fine. More specifically, what are you getting when you run `jQuery`?

Comment: I think it would be better to wrap jQuery so that it only works within firebug

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load JQuery into any page using Firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853692/load-jquery-into-any-page-using-firebug)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like others have said, it wont work unless you have jquery included on the page. However, you can easily include jQuery on any page with this bookmarklet: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet

Comment: I added this JQuerfier bookmarklet.  I don't get any errors but all that outputs on the console is the command I entered.  For example, jQuery("#a_current_val").text() results in:
>>> jQuery("#a_current_val").text()
 The content of the textbox does not output.

Comment: weird, I'm used to firebug showing the result. Have you tried console.log(jQuery('#a_current_val').text())

also try just jQuery('#a_current_val') to make sure that you haven't mistyped the id of the element. (it should return an array, empty if no element matches the id)

Answer (score 10):

Just put this before your code in firebug console:

`include("jquery");`

[more...](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-include-command/)

Comment: Why did my comment disappear? I said that this was the best answer on the page but it should probably be include("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js", "jquery")

Comment: Yes, worked for me too! After including jquery with Firebug Console, the following message information appeared in console: jquery-latest.js properly included.