# Load JQuery into any page using Firebug

Tags: jquery, firebug

Does anyone have a snippet to load jquery onto any page from firebug? I often come across sites that I would prefer to inspect using familiar jq syntax.

For example, say I want to extract a list of prices from a page - it would be nice to launch firebug, install jquery from the google CDN, and type $('li.prices').each(...).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running jQuery call in Firebug Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851665/running-jquery-call-in-firebug-console)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just saw this [bookmarklet for injecting jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet) in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851665/running-jquery-call-in-firebug-console)

Comment: Tested on Mac Chrome 16. Works great!

Comment: Works in Linux Firefox 36 too

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to paste this to the Firebug console and hit the execute button.

```
var fileref = document.createElement("script");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js");
document.head.appendChild(fileref);
```

UPDATE: Use following snippet to inject jQuery into a website that uses HTTPS:

```
var fileref = document.createElement("script");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js");
document.head.appendChild(fileref);
```

Comment: I got `Blocked loading mixed active content "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"`.

Comment: Are you trying to inject that snippet into a HTTPS website?
If yes, try to change the jquery url to "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js". This may help.

Comment: That didn't help on https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/ . But after going past your answer I found http://stackoverflow.com/a/31566296/733092 down below it, which solved it in one line.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution. Please note that the Stackoverflow software modified my link. It removed the HTTPS that I wrote in front of the link. I tested that with the website you posted and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `include` function from the Console with either the URL to jQuery or by using the predefined alias, like this:

```
include("jquery")
```

See [here](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Include) for more detail.

Comment: How lucky for me that the easy correct answer got posted three days before I looked at this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

check out  [jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/06/updated-jquery-bookmarklet)

Comment: This is an older version of EMiller's suggestion.

Comment: thumbs up for using the proper name